# Javascript setTimeout on Mouseleave event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that appears when the user's mouse leaves the document with a survey about my site.

I don't want to ask them to do the survey if they move their mouse out in the first couple of minutes while browsing around, so I was wondering if I can set a timeout/sleep on when this mouseleave function would activate.

Here is my code without the timeout:

```
        $(document).mouseleave(function () {
        document.getElementById("Overlay1").style.display = "";
        });
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window.setTimeout` to enable the function after a certain time.

Example:

```
    window.setTimeout(function(){
    $(document).mouseleave(function () {
            console.log('mouse leave');
            document.getElementById("Overlay1").style.display = "";
            });
        console.log('initiated');
    },5000);
```

Comment: I'm sorry im not too good at javascript, i put your code above mine but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

you could call the same function encapsulated in a`setTimeout` function call :

```
 $(document).mouseleave(function() {
    var seconds = 3;

    //execute the function in 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("Overlay1").style.display = "";
    },seconds*1000);
 });
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't seem to show it even after 3 seconds, and dreamweaver says there is a syntax error on the line:
 setTimeout(fucntion(){

Comment: sry, i had a typo :D "fucntion" instead of "function".see edit

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, works but it keeps popping it up a lot, the other posters example works perfectly, thanks for the help though!!